# Best open source lightweight "Packagable" DB for a desktop application

Tags: java, database

I am making a Java desktop application which involves lot of data, state, etc.
I must store all this data in a DB for querying purposes.

Now if I distribute my application I will have to distribute the DB packaged along with the
application itself.

Which is the best open source "Packagable" DB which I can use for this purpose.?
(assuming say my application is for commercial purpose)

I don't want the end-users of my application to install a DB like MySQL seperately

I want it to be part of my application .msi(or zipped) installer, at the sametime it should not be too large (>50MB) and it should not require the user to take any additional steps for installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no **best**, but suitable. Try sqlite, its relatively fast, simple db library. Free

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend a *best* database, but I like using the Derby DB (or Java DB which is Oracle's Derby distribution).